# Setting an child property to null

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I am currently creating an application for migrating data, The data can be very complex as it can contain itself e.g

```
--Boss
   --Supervisor
      ---Manager
          ---Supervisor
            ---Boss
              ----Employee
```

The application then shows the data as a checkbox where a use can select what data they want, the issue now is that behind the scenes I load the data and want to keep a separate list of the original source where i get the data from.

The issue is, if i wanted to decrease the size of the Boss object(the top level one, would setting null on the supervisor object decrease its memory size, or would it just create an orphaned element in memory and just increase my application memory use?

NB. The Elements the in hierarchy all come from the same base type and are in the format of List ..of Lists...Of lists ..,etc with other properties attached to them that might be of the same base type that cannot be shown on the hierarchy.

This is an example of the code i am using

```
public class AttributeConversion : BaseConversion
    {

        public AttributeConversion(string displayName)
            : base(displayName)
        {
            //set up value
        }

        public AttributeConversion()
        {
            //default constructor for the serializer class
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        [Identity]
        public int AttributeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //[XmlIgnore]
        public int DataTypeID { get; set; }

        [ControlAttribute]
        [XmlArray("AttributeLookupSets")]
        [XmlArrayItem("AttributeLookupSet")]
        public List<AttributeLookupSetConversion> AttributeLookupSetConversions { get; set; }

        public AttributeLookupSourceConversion AttributeLookupSource { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AttributeSetAttribute")]
        public AttributeSetAttributeConversion AttributeSetAttributeConversion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AttributeInteger")]
        public AttributeIntegerConversion AttributeIntegerConversion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AttributeFloat")]
        public AttributeFloatConversion AttributeFloatConversion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AttributeText")]
        public AttributeTextConversion AttributeTextConversion { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AttributeDate")]
        public AttributeDateConversion AttributeDateConversion { get; set; }
```

So in this particular instance, I would like to nullify all the objects with either XmlElement or XmlArray attributes. The goal is to flatten that hierarchy and then set all items to null, that way I can use the list for reference as to what Items I have at anytime in the hierarchy of objects, But I am unsure of the memory usage, so I wanted to at least ensure i shed any memory i might be wasting.

Comment: Assuming all of these are `class`es then setting the reference to `null` won't change the size of the `Boss` object at all (it only stored a reference after all). It *may* cause the `Supervisor` object to be cleaned up on the next GC pass (if no other reference to it exists)

Comment: You should explain *why* you need to decrease the size of the `Boss` object at all (and what all these types are and how they are increasing the size to an unacceptable amount)

Comment: @mahlatse, can you show us an example of the code you have? That `List ..of Lists...Of lists ..,` make me think that maybe you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Well the boss object size won't change as unholysheep said, but you'll use less memory because the rest of the object hierarchy wont be created. What is your intention here?

Comment: The objects are created from and xml deserialization, so the data is already there, I wanted to extract the whole XML hierarchy, flatten it into a list of everything available, remove duplicated and then nullify the child values and use that as a reference for a quick search of what items i have in my hierarchy at all times

Comment: @UnholySheep , I use a deep copy to create the reference list from the original object, so there shouldn't be anymore references on it.

Comment: @mahlatse, if you do that and clear your original object, don't think you will have memory wasting. If you need an improvement, you can create similar classes, but without the unused relations. For example, create a class AttributeConversionWithoutRelations, that only contains the important data.

Comment: @bruno.almeida, I wanted to keep the architecture as simple as possible, creating new classes will create a whole new scenario as I have over 70 classes already created to hold my data. Creating a skimmed version would require a translator object for each class.